# Finding the implementation of (SimpleHTTPServer) Class in mininet

Tags: mininet, openflow

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80 &
```

is used to run HTTP server in `Mininet`. I want to find the file that contains the implementation of `SimpleHTTPServer` so I can modify the code to run HTTP server based on my requirement. Where do I find it? I searched in Mininet directory but I did not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleHTTPServer is a part of the standard python library.

Docs can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)